# paginate_links() on page (shortcode output)

Tags: wp-query, pagination

On a standard WordPress page, I have a `WP Query` that runs through a post type I created. Along with that query, I am using [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) to generate pagination. While the standard (no permalinks) seems to work fine - when enabling any permalink combination, the subsequent pagination pages do not load. Here is what I have so far:

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'galleries',
    'paged'     => get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_type' => 'galleries'
);

$posts_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
$i = 0; // count
$total_items = $posts_query->post_count; // total profiles
$number_columns = $galleries_options['columns']; // number of columns
if ($posts_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div id="galleries-list">';
    while ($posts_query->have_posts() && ($i < $total_items)) { ?>
        <?php $posts_query->the_post(); if ($i % $number_columns == 0) echo ($i > 0 ? '</div><div class="row">' : '<div class="row first-row">'); ?>
        <div class="<?php echo 'width'.intval(100 / $number_columns); ?> <?php if ($i % $number_columns == 0) echo 'first-item'; ?>">
            <?php
                galleries_list(get_the_ID());
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    $total_pages = $posts_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer 
    if ($total_pages > 1){  
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));  
        echo '<nav class="page-nav">';  
        echo paginate_links(array(  
            'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'    => '?paged=%#%',  
            'current'   => $current_page,  
            'total'     => $total_pages,  
            'prev_text' => 'Prev',  
            'next_text' => 'Next'  
        ));  
        echo '</nav>';  
    } 

}
```

The default URL is `?page_id=60&paged=2` which works/loads fine - yet `galleries/page/2/` does not. Anyone have any suggestions? I'm using the exact same thing for taxonomy pagination... so I'm a bit confused on why this isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you're not using native custom post type/taxonomy archives?

Comment: This archive is generated via a shortcode that is applied to a page.

Comment: Gotcha ;) So when you say "don't load", do you get *anything*? Does the page that has the shortcode still appear okay?

Comment: Oddly enough I'm getting a 404 :/

Comment: Sounds like a rewrite mismatch - use a plugin like [Rewrite Rules Inspector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/), screencap/copypaste to pastebin & report back :)

Comment: Here's a screencap of the galleries post type http://postimage.org/image/ips4lnlwj/ Thanks!

Comment: You should disable rewrite rules for your galleries post type (`'rewrite' => false`) - they're conflicting with the standard rules for your page with slug `galleries`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being the page in which I was accessing the shortcode on was using the same slug - which WP was freaking out about. While I'll need to investigate why it would happen, was easy enough to fix.